# Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) not working

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to hide rows based on the value in cell B3. This was working for me earlier but I unfortunately can't figure out what I changed. I right clicked on the tab and pasted this in 'View Code'. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
If Range("B3") = "a" Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows("40:43").EntireRow.Hidden = False
ElseIf Range("B3") = "b" Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows("40:43").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I opened and closed Excel and now this code works.

Comment: glad i could help    (/s)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but if you already using the `Target`, why not use it full capabilities:

```
If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
    If Target.Value2 = "a" Then ' <-- use Target.Value2
        Rows("40:43").EntireRow.Hidden = False ' <-- there's no need to use ActiveSheet
    ElseIf Target.Value2 = "b" Then
        Rows("40:43").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
```

**Note**: there's no need to use `ActiveSheet`, as this event is triggered inside the `ActiveSheet`.

---

You can use `Select Case` if you will need to add more scenarios in the future:

```
If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
    Select Case Target.Value2
        Case "a"
            Rows("40:43").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case "b"
            Rows("40:43").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Else ' in case you want add more scenarios in the future
            ' do something else...
    End Select
End If
```